# Why does $\lim_{x \to \infty} \big(1 + \frac{1}{x}\big)^x = \lim_{x \to 0} \big(1 + x\big)^{\frac{1}{x}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

Is there a way to make sense of that relationship? Could you derive one from the other algebraically?

It looks like the first limit approaches $e$ from lower values (for positive $x$ values) whereas the second limit approaches $e$ from greater values, but i'm not sure what to make of that.

(I included the calculus tag because I've only seen the second limit in the context of trying to find the derivative of $\log(x)$)

Comment: It results simply from the change of variable $\;t=\dfrac1x$.

Comment: @Bernard, ah I think I get it. $\lim_{t \to \infty} \big(\frac{1}{t}\big)$ is equivalent to $\lim_{t \to 0} (t) $, is that right?

Comment: That's because the change of variable is defined by a decreasing function. B. t. w. you should add that $x$ tends to $\color{red}{+}\infty$ and $0^{\color{red}{+}}$ respectively.

Comment: @Bernard, why only $+ \infty$ and $0$ from the positive side? It looks like the limits approach $e$ from both the positive and negative sides in the case of $0$ and that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \big(1 + \frac{1}{x}\big)^x$ also approaches $e$.

Comment: You're right. I don't remember why I thought so (probably I used x^x during my calculations, which isn't necessary).

Comment: @Bernard, Thanks for confirming. I'm so used to misunderstanding stuff that I just assumed I was missing something.

Comment: And you can even have $x$ going to complex infinity in the first, and to complex $0$ in the second.

Comment: @GEdgar You sure about that?  A complex exponent causes us some issues you know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start with the following substitution:$$t=\frac1x$$Putting this in the first equation gives us $$(1+t)^{1/t}$$

We also have to be careful with the limit, noting$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x=\lim_{t\to0^+}t$$Using this, we deduce that after substitution, our limit should come out to say $$\lim_{t\to0^+}(1+t)^{1/t}$$

Comment: If $x \to \infty$, then $t \to 0^{+}$.

Comment: @Simple Art Thank you, the part about $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = \lim_{t \to 0^+} t$ is what was confusing me.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff No problem.  Do you want me to redo it?

Comment: @SimpleArt, No thank you, I just meant that the equivalence of those limits is what I was failing to grasp conceptually, and you clarified that. (I might be misunderstanding what you just meant about "redoing it", though)

Comment: @jeremyradcliff No problem.  By redoing it, I just meant to add more words/explanations.

Comment: @SimpleArt, It's all very clear now, but thank you for offering and happy Holidays to you :)

Comment: @jeremyradcliff Always my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

**The complex case**
$$
(1+x)^{1/x} = \exp\left(\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\right)
$$
by definition.  For complex $x$ with $|x|<1$, the principal value of log has expansion
$$
\log(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \cdots
$$
a power series with radius of convergence $1$.
Then
$$
\frac{\log(1+x)}{x} = 1 - \frac{x}{2} + \cdots
$$
also a power series with radius of convergence $1$.
The complex limit
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x} = 1
$$
exists, and thus the complex limit
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\;(1+x)^{1/x} = \exp(1)
$$
also exists.

The substitution in the other answers shows that the complex limit
$$
\lim_{z \to \infty}\;\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^z = \exp(1)
$$
also.

Comment: Thank you for adding this explanation, it's very interesting.